# Change datagridview cell color by clicking in c#(winform)

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell

I have a datagrid on the form.
and i want to that,
when i click on any cell on any row
the cell back color can change to red color for example.
how can i do that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use cell click event

in the event just assign cell.backcolor to color.red

private void GridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

```
    private void GridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){

        DataGridViewCellStyle CellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style = CellStyle;

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change the DefaultCellStyle. For example:

```
...
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DataGridViewCell cell;

cell = datagridview1[0,0];  // location of cell
cell.Style.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;  // or whatever color you want
```

This could be placed in a loop etc., using the indices.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting it in the **Cell_Enter** event

**OR**

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Value != null)
     {
         if (condition)
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 160, 160);
     }               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update from 2022, working with Visual Studio 2022, to the right answer of the user @Umesh CHILAKA.

DataGridViewCellStyle has BackColor property, meaning you can access this directly, so you can consider to use the following, as it will work too:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red
```

Another plus of this aproach is that you don't create another object DataGridViewCellStyle.